# Python 8-puzzle IDDFS with results greater than BFS

Tags: python, python-3.x

My **Iterative Deepening Depth-First Search** (**IDDFS**) of the 8 puzzle game returns a path length greater than my BFS. The total number of visited Nodes is *42* for the **IDDFS** while my **BFS** returns a total of *26*. Is there something wrong with my **IDDFS** algorithm or is that just how it should behave???

```
import collections
import queue
import time
import itertools

class Node:

    def __init__(self, puzzle, last=None):
        self.puzzle = puzzle
        self.last = last

    @property
    def seq(self): # to keep track of the sequence used to get to the goal
        node, seq = self, []
        while node:
            seq.append(node)
            node = node.last
        yield from reversed(seq)

    @property
    def state(self):
        return str(self.puzzle.board) # hashable so it can be compared in sets

    @property
    def isSolved(self):
        return self.puzzle.isSolved

    @property
    def getMoves(self):
        return self.puzzle.getMoves

class Puzzle:

    def __init__(self, startBoard):
        self.board = startBoard

    @property
    def getMoves(self):

        possibleNewBoards = []

        zeroPos = self.board.index(0) # find the zero tile to determine possible moves

        if zeroPos == 0:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(0,1))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(0,3))
        elif zeroPos == 1:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(1,0))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(1,2))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(1,4))
        elif zeroPos == 2:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(2,1))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(2,5))
        elif zeroPos == 3:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(3,0))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(3,4))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(3,6))
        elif zeroPos == 4:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(4,1))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(4,3))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(4,5))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(4,7))
        elif zeroPos == 5:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(5,2))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(5,4))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(5,8))
        elif zeroPos == 6:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(6,3))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(6,7))
        elif zeroPos == 7:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(7,4))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(7,6))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(7,8))
        else:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(8,5))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(8,7))

        return possibleNewBoards # returns Puzzle objects (maximum of 4 at a time)

    def move(self, current, to):

        changeBoard = self.board[:] # create a copy
        changeBoard[to], changeBoard[current] = changeBoard[current], changeBoard[to] # switch the tiles at the passed positions
        return Puzzle(changeBoard) # return a new Puzzle object

    def printPuzzle(self): # prints board in 8 puzzle style

        copyBoard = self.board[:]
        for i in range(9):
            if i == 2 or i == 5:
                print((str)(copyBoard[i]))
            else:
                print((str)(copyBoard[i])+" ", end="")
        print('\n')

    @property
    def isSolved(self):
        return self.board == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] # goal board

class Solver:

    def __init__(self, Puzzle):
        self.puzzle = Puzzle

    def IDDFS(self):

        def DLS(currentNode, depth):
            if depth == 0:
                return None
            if currentNode.isSolved:
                return currentNode
            elif depth > 0:
                for board in currentNode.getMoves:
                    nextNode = Node(board, currentNode)
                    if nextNode.state not in visited:
                        visited.add(nextNode.state)
                        goalNode = DLS(nextNode, depth - 1)
                        if goalNode != None: # I thought this should be redundant but it never finds a soln if I take it out
                            if goalNode.isSolved: # same as above ^
                                return goalNode

        for depth in itertools.count():
            visited = set()
            startNode = Node(self.puzzle)
            print(startNode.isSolved)
            goalNode = DLS(startNode, depth)
            if goalNode != None:
                if goalNode.isSolved:
                    return goalNode.seq

startingBoard = [7,2,4,5,0,6,8,3,1]

myPuzzle = Puzzle(startingBoard)
mySolver = Solver(myPuzzle)
start = time.time()
goalSeq = mySolver.IDDFS()
end = time.time()

counter = -1 # starting state doesn't count as a move
for node in goalSeq:
    counter = counter + 1
    node.puzzle.printPuzzle()
print("Total number of moves: " + str(counter))
totalTime = end - start
print("Total searching time: %.2f seconds" % (totalTime))
```

Comment: Both IDDFS and BFS should be guaranteed to return a minimal-depth path. Since they return different depths, one must be broken. It's natural for IDDFS to visit more nodes, since it's not as time efficient as BFS, but it is more memory efficient (won't have to keep track of as many nodes at once).

Comment: @machineyearning That is what I feared. I have confirmed that this puzzle has an optimal solution at length 26. I am thinking it has something to do with the way I find the path (`Node.seq`) after I have found the goal Node because I also have an A* solution that finds the goal node in 0.04 seconds but with 54 moves ...